# Can't expand JSON file in SQL Server using OPENJSON beyond 1st level

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, open-json

I am working with JSON that has been inserted into a SQL table and I have been trying to expand the dataset.  So far I have been unable to expand beyond a single.

The data looks like this in the database. A single record with JSON.

[image]

I have been able to expand the data with the following query:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @json =  (Select [JSON] FROM TableLocation)

SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON (@json)
```

I have confirmed that all the records are there, however, I haven't been able to expand it beyond this level.  Most of the documentation I have found online doesn't reference if the hierarchy is blank.  Any assistance would be great.

[image]

I have tried reference the ID column (or any other columns), however if I do I get a column of nulls.

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @json =  (Select [JSON] FROM TableLocation)

SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON (@json)
    WITH (
        ID nvarchar(4000) '$.id')
```

[image]

Comment: Case Sensitive issue... "ID" in the table.... "id" in your OPENJSON statement...

Comment: Trying changing '$.id' to '$.ID' - it's case sensitive.

Comment: It looks like that is it.  I am not used to case sensitivity and would have sworn I tried it with ID already.